Trying to keep the .gitlab/workflows directory when mirroring from gitlab to github
I'm trying to mirror my GitLab repo into GitHub.
I am using this script for:
git clone https://oauth2:${token}@{gitlab repo}
cd {name}

git remote set-url --push origin https://oauth2:${Github token}@{github repo}
git checkout main || git checkout -b main
git pull origin main
git push --force origin main
git checkout develop || git checkout -b develop
git pull origin develop
git push --force origin develop
git push --mirror

And this works fine. The only problem is that the .github/workflows directory I make in GitHub always get deleted. I've tried multiple ways to clone them into this mirror and push them all together, but nothing seems to work. Does anyone know of a way to make them persist?
